# Run a loop every x seconds in python in order to scrape a website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-multithreading

I'm scraping a website and when I'm running my script, it crashes the API request. I'd like to iterate the loop with a break of 3 seconds between each iteration.

```
def printit():
    country_list_id = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    product_list_id = ['1', '2', '3']

    for c in country_list_id:
       for p in product_list_id:
          url = "https://www.example.com/api/country_id=" + c + "&product_id=" + p + "&option="
        test(url)

def test(url_final):
        get_url = requests.get(url_final)
        get_text = get_url.text
        print(get_text)
        #I'd like to make a small break here before it iterate again


printit()
```

Comment: Have you tried [time.sleep](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep)?

Comment: I didn't think it was that simple, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [time](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/time.html) module:

```
import time

     def printit():
        country_list_id = ['a', 'b', 'c']
        product_list_id = ['1', '2', '3']

        for c in country_list_id:
           for p in product_list_id:
              url = "https://www.example.com/api/country_id=" + c + "&product_id=" + p + "&option="
            test(url)

    def test(url_final):
            get_url = requests.get(url_final)
            get_text = get_url.text
            print(get_text)
            time.sleep(3)


    printit()
```

Answer (score 1):

First, import `time`:

```
import time
```

then `sleep` for `3`:

```
time.sleep(3)
```